# Is Kombucha tea, which has alcohol added to, halal?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol

Does the alcohol in Kombucha tea make it haraam?

I just want to drink it for its benefits but I don't know if its halal or haraam. It's full of enzymes, probiotics, and antioxidants.

Comment: What is the reason of adding alcohol if it can be good without it?

Comment: The alcohol is produced through fermentation from what I understand by reading about it online.

Comment: As far as I think, Alcohol is haram. In some cases you can have haram things to use but does it applies to alcohol or not, not sure. Wait for your answer

Comment: https://www.smh.com.au/business/consumer-affairs/alcohol-content-of-kombucha-kefir-could-put-unsuspecting-drinkers-over-the-limit-20190926-p52v1v.html a recent study suggests they could pose a risk to unsuspecting drinkers who think they are consuming an alcohol-free product.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a Hadith regarding this:

> That the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Whatever a lot of it intoxicates, a little of it is unlawful."
>
> He said: There are narrations on this topic from Sa'd, 'Aishah, 'Abdullah bin 'Amr, Ibn 'Umar, and Khawwat bin Jubair.
>
> [Abu 'Eisa said:] This Hadith is Hasan Gharib as a narration of Jabir. 
> [Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1865 - Vol. 3, Book 24, Hadith 1865](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/26/5)

And Allah Knows Best.

Comment: Please consider citing the hadith for meeting site standards on quality content.

Answer (score 1):

AssalamuAlaikum, The alcohol in Kombucha is in trace amounts and no matter how much you drink it, will not intoxicate you. That makes it Halal, In Shaa Allah. Please refer to http://islamqa.info/en/146710 for complete answer. Please correct me if I am wrong here. Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification: Alcohol is not added to kombucha. It's a fermentation by-product. The levels are quite low; it's not practical to drink enough to intoxicate yourself. (There are natural alcohols in fruit, bread, etc.)